# Nesting JavaScript every & some

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out why this is returning false:

```js
var goodUsers = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 },
];

var testUsers = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 }
];

console.log(testUsers.every(testUser => {
  goodUsers.some(goodUser => {
    testUser.id === goodUser.id
  })
}));
```

I think my problem is with how I am nesting `some` inside of `every`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just as a note, this has a complexity of n ^ 2, meaning it would be pretty slow for large arrays. You could take advantage of the new Set object in ES6 and do something like: `const idSet = new Set(goodUsers.map(goodUser => goodUser.id)); testUsers.every(testUser => idSet.has(testUser.id));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your callbacks for `.some` and `.every` didn't actually *return* anything.  That's why you were getting `false`.

```js
var goodUsers = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 },
];

var testUsers = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 }
];

console.log(testUsers.every(testUser => {
  return goodUsers.some(goodUser => {
    return testUser.id === goodUser.id
  });
}));
```

There is a difference between doing:

```
goodUser => testUser.id === goodUser.id
```

and

```
goodUser => { testUser.id === goodUser.id; }
```

The first - ***without*** `{}` - has an *implicit* `return`.  It returns the value of the expression.  It's the same as doing:

```
goodUser => { return testUser.id === goodUser.id; }
```

You were using `{}`, which starts a block of statements, and left out the `return` statement.

DOCS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Ah, OK. I was under the impression that there was an implicit `return` for arrow functions. This is a case when it's not?

Comment: Or indeed, `console.log(testUesrs.every(testUser => goodUsers.some(goodUser => testUser.id === goodUser.id)));`

Comment: @WilliamC: There is in the *concise* form, which doesn't use `{}`; when you use the longer form with `{}`, there is no implicit return.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Excellent. Thanks for the info. Cheers.

Comment: @T.J. how can we name arrows with/without block syntax properly in order to distinguish them?

Comment: @LUH3417: That's largely just the same sentence I didn't understand the first time. Do you mean, what can we call an arrow function with a concise body as distinct from an arrow function with a normal body? For the first, I've heard "concise arrow function" or "arrow function with concise body" (the spec uses *ConciseBody* for that syntax element). I haven't heard a specific term for an arrow function with a normal function body.

Comment: @T.J. Sorry, I'm not a native speaker. "concise arrow" is more concise then "arrow with `{}`" or "arrow with block scope". Best I've heard so far.